# pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'uvloop>=0.14.0' distribution was not found and is required by uvicorn

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

```
File "/usr/bin/uvicorn", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3254, in <module>
    def _initialize_master_working_set():
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3237, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3266, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 584, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 901, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 787, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'uvloop>=0.14.0' distribution was not found and is required by uvicorn
```

Comment: This is because you've installed the minimum version of uvicorn - if you need the websocket dependencies, you should install `uvicorn[standard]` instead - `pip install uvicorn[standard]`

Answer (score 1):

***install this package fastapi-socketio.***

your error is gone away.

this is basic packages requirement for fastapi run

```
bidict==0.21.3
click==7.1.2
fastapi==0.68.1
fastapi-socketio==0.0.8
h11==0.9.0
httptools==0.1.2
pydantic==1.8.2
python-engineio==4.2.1
python-socketio==5.4.0
starlette==0.14.2
typing-extensions==3.10.0.2
uvicorn==0.11.5
uvloop==0.16.0
websockets==8.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add `uvloop=*` at your Pipfile, then install it with command `pipenv install`

Answer (score -2):

install this package fastapi-socketio.

> fastapi-socketio==0.0.8

your error is gone away.

**check basic packages requirement for FASTAPI**

```
bidict==0.21.3
click==7.1.2
fastapi==0.68.1
fastapi-socketio==0.0.8
h11==0.9.0
httptools==0.1.2
pydantic==1.8.2
python-engineio==4.2.1
python-socketio==5.4.0
starlette==0.14.2
typing-extensions==3.10.0.2
uvicorn==0.11.5
uvloop==0.16.0
websockets==8.1
```

Comment: add comments for your answer